# Can I easily change Sonicwall's rules from one interface to another if I physically change interfaces?

Tags: sonicwall, interface

In our Sonicwall, we want to unplug our cat5 cable from X0, and instead use a optical fiber into X16.  But this would mean changing all our rules (we have many VLAN sub-interfaces and firewall rules).

Is there an easier way to pull this off than to manually create new VLANS and change each rule from X0 to X16?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If X0 and X16 interfaces are bound to the same zone (eg: LAN), you don't need to change anything regarding firewall rules, as they are not interface-specific.

However, VLANs and some NAT rules, being interface-specific, will need reconfiguration.